# Why has my Android app suddenly stopped displaying dialogs?

Tags: android-alertdialog

My app displays dialogs, warning the user of various situations and requiring user input.  These dialogs were all working fine, but now they are no longer displaying; after upgrading from Android Studio 'Chipmunk' to 'Giraffe'.  Dialogs do currently display when invoked from the Menu, for example when Quit is selected from the menu, a dialog asking if user really wants to quit works correctly.  The following code displays the quit dialog:

```
    public void showAlertQuit(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

However, whenever a dialog is called as a result of the user clicking a button, the dialog is no longer displayed.  The prime example being when the user clicks the 'Connect' button as follows:

```
    public void onClickConnect(View view) {
        // For running on the emulator which does not support bluetooth
        if (inEmulator) {
            address = "00:11:22:33:44:55";
            conntype = "bluetooth";
            setUiLaps(true);
            deviceConnected = true;
            TString = textView.getText().toString();
            TString = TString + "\nConnection opened to " + address + ".\nSet laps > 0.";
            textView.setText(TString);
            lapsHead.setText(R.string.set_laps);
            // get the track associated with the address of the timer
            processTimerAddress();
            startVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("startVol")));
            falseVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("falseVol")));
            winVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("winVol")));
            oMenu.setGroupVisible(0, false);  // hide the options menu
        } else { // running on actual hardware
            /*
             * Try to connect to a BlueTooth Device that will be sending lap signals
             * Launch the BTDeviceListActivity to see the available devices and/or do a scan
             */
            Intent serverIntent = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                serverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BTDeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, Constants.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            }
        }
    }


    public void processTimerAddress() {
        // look for a timer and the active track
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
        trackId = db.GetActiveTrackByConnectAddr(conntype, address);
        if (trackId == -1) { // timer not found, timer and track must be added
            showTimerAlert("Timer Absent", "Timer with connection: " + conntype + " - " + 
                    address + ",  does not exist.\n" +
                    "Lets add the Timer and Track");
        } else if (trackId == 0) { // timer exists, but there is no active track
            int timerid = db.GetTimerByConnect(conntype, address);
            showNoTrackAlert( "Active Track Missing", "Timer with connection: " + conntype + " - " +
                    address + ", is present.\n" +
                    "However, there is no active track.  Lets add a track for this timer", timerid);
        } else { // a track exists for this race
            // get the track and lane information for this track
            trackLaneData = db.GetTrackByTrackId(trackId);
            laneCnt = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("lanecnt")));
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> laneList = db.GetLanesByTrackId(trackId);
            int s = laneList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                trackLaneData.add(laneList.get(i));
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }


    public void showTimerAlert(String title, String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Show Timer Alert " + title);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> startAddTimerTrack());
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

[Screen shot of app showing menu and click of Quit option.  Exit Slot Racer is displayed. However, when the Connect button is clicked, dialogs are not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8uHk.png)

I have made some test modifications:

1. Added a call to **showTimerAlert** from within the menu; this, ends up properly displaying the Timer Alert dialog.
2. Added a call to **showAlertQuit** from within the **onClickConnect** method, just before the if statement, and just before the call to **processTimerAddress**, thereby expecting the Alert Quit dialog to be displayed when clicking the Connect button; the Alert Quit dialog is not displayed.

I have also tried various contexts within my ...Alert methods:
     `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`
such as MainActivity.this;
     `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);`
as well as creating a global Context object, setting context = this within onClickConnect
     `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`
None of which have worked.

Thanks to all very much for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE FIXED; This was due to a combination of two issues:

1. The assumption that code executes sequentially.
2. The modification of variable names in regards to character case.

```
....

    // get the track associated with the address of the timer
            processTimerAddress();
            startVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("startVol")));
            falseVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("falseVol")));
            winVol = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(trackLaneData.get(0).get("winVol")));
            oMenu.setGroupVisible(0, false);  // hide the options menu

....
```

I modified the capitalization of the terms 'startVol', 'falseVol' & 'winVol', thereby causing a NUllPointerException when the above was executed; they should be 'startvol', 'falsevol', 'winvol'

I was assuming the call to the method processTimerAddress(), which displays an ALERT dialog, would execute prior to the lines following the call which were generating the NullPointException; a bad assumption.